# Compare two sets cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$X:= \left\{ f \in \{{0,1}\}^\mathbb R\mid f\text{ non-decreasing  monotonic function}\right\} $

$Y:= \left\{ g \in \mathbb R^{\{0,1\}}\mid g\text{ non-decreasing monotonic function}\right\} $

Which cardinality set is bigger ? (or equal)

I know how to find Y cardinality:

$ |Y|\leq|\mathbb R|^{|{\{0,1\}}|}=\aleph^2=\aleph. $

The constant functions of $\mathbb R$ has power $\aleph $ so $\aleph \leq |Y|$

$|Y|=\aleph$ (Cantor Bernstein)

I have no idea how to find $|X|$.

Help please ?

Comment: Hint: ${\{0,1\}}^\mathbb R$ is a set of all binary (two-valued) functions on a real domain. $\mathbb R^{\{0,1\}}$ is a set of all real functions on a binary (two-point) domain.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the map $f \to (a,f(a))$ where $a =\sup \{x: f(x)=0\}$. Verify that this is one-to-one and conclude that $|X|=c$.  [ $(x,0)$ and $(x,1)$ are both in the range of this map for every real number $x$].

As pointed out by Paul Sinclair in the comment below there is a problem with the constant functions $0$ and $1$ but that does not alter the cardinality.

Comment: A small problem with this is that both the constant $0$ and constant $1$ functions are in $X$, and for those $a = \infty, -\infty$, respectively, which are not in the domain of $f$. But eliminating those two functions only changes the cardinality by $2$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for the comment.